# Python remove spaces and append

Tags: python, string, text, growlnotify

I am currently writing a growl notification plugin for emesene messenger on OS X. It is nearly working except to when it comes to displaying a message snippet.

The message is passed to growlnotify as a variable, however growl does not accept spaces in the displayed message.

So what i need help with is a script to remove the spaces between multiple words and replace it with a \ then a space.

e.g.
Original: This is a message
What is needed: This\ is\ a\ message

I have looked around at similar answers but i could not work out how to append the slash.

Comment: I just realized that this will be a big problem if the message contains any backslashes or other escape sequences. i.e. `this\ message` will become `this\\ message` and the space won't be escaped. That's why you should follow @Ignacio's advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of trying to do this with `os.system()`, use [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) instead, passing the program and arguments as a list.

Answer (score 5):

Just use the `replace` method of the string class:

```python
message_string = "This is a message"
print message_string.replace(" ", "\ ")
```

returns:

```
$ python test.py
This\ is\ a\ message
```

See [Python string.replace documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.replace).

Comment: Also take a look at @Ignacio 's answer. That is likely a more suitable way of solving your problem, and overall a lot safer.

Answer (score 3):

```
message = "This is a message"
print message.replace( " ", "\ " )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the `replace` method of strings.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone's using replace, so here's the other solution:

```
print '\ '.join(message.split(' '))
```

Comment: This will lose runs of multiple spaces, plus all tabs and other whitespace.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: Not anymore.