# Using Python subprocess rather than os.system

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, os.system

Following the advice of Ignacio ( [Python remove spaces and append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289915/python-remove-spaces-and-append/6289940#6289940) ) I am trying to convert the below command to use `subprocess` rather than `os.system`.

The script: `os.system("/usr/local/bin/growlnotify -n emesene -a emesene -t """+title+""" -m """+text+"""""")`

I would of thought: `subprocess.call(['/usr/local/bin/growlnotify', '-n emesene', '-a emesene', '-t ""+title+"""', '-m """+text+"""""'], shell=True)`

But it doesnt work. Any ideas how to get this working? I've looked at the Python docs and looked here, but i cannot figure it out!

BTW the `title` and `text` are variables from emesene messengers notification system

Comment: consider to accept Ignacio's answer in the linked question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want "shell=True" when you use a list to pass the command.
I would have merely commented as such on Jeremy Banks's post (since his statement on shlex.split is most notable), but I don't currently have the rep to do so :/

```
subprocess.call(['/usr/local/bin/growlnotify', '-n',  'emesene', '-a', 'emesene', '-t', title, '-m', text])
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
subprocess.call(['/usr/local/bin/growlnotify', '-n emesene', '-a emesene', '-t ""+title+"""', '-m """+text+"""""'], shell=True)
```

use

```
subprocess.call(['/usr/local/bin/growlnotify', '-n',  'emesene', '-a', 'emesene', '-t', title, '-m', text], shell=True)
```

Everywhere you have an unquoted space in the shell command, split another list item.

The [shlex.split](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) function can be used to convert from a shell-style command to a list of the sort Subproces expects.

Comment: Doesn't work. Gives a blank notification, so i guess its not taking the variables.